# How can I include the js and css file of my custom theme dynamically in header.php

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

I am creating a simple theme in wordpress.The problem is that number of assets that are present in js and css folder are not same in every case i.e. the number of .css files in css folders may change and so is the case for .js files. I tried using scandir() function of php to read the directory e.g

```
    $files = scandir(get_template_directory_uri().'/js');
```

also

```
    $files = scandir('js');
```

As I am writing the code in header.php.
 Got no luck reading the files.
Any help will be appreciated greatly.
I also gave complete permission 777 to my wp-content folder.

Comment: It seems that you want to include the files automatically, not dynamically. Can you explain further what you are trying to do? The first recomendation is: do not do it in header.php.

Comment: What do you want to do further? `scandir()` will provide you the list of all files. You want to make an array of those and process that for something or search for any specific file?

Let us know the end use so question will be specific and users may suggest another way of implementation. Also, agreed with @cybmeta that you should not do these checks in `header.php` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted to enqueue all the files in your css and js directory of your theme. Thats the reason you are trying to use the `scandir()`. `get_template_directory_uri()` returns URL not the directory path. You need to use `get_template_directory()` for directory.

If you wanted to do that, then do it in functions.php

```
function enqueue_all_front_resources(){

   $js_directory = get_template_directory().'/js/';
   $all_js_files = array_diff(scandir($js_directory), array('..', '.'));
   // to avoid .. and . from the scandir function i used array_diff

   //now add the js with wp_enqueue_script()
   foreach($all_js_files as $js_file){
     wp_enqueue_script( $js_file.'-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/'.$js_file );
   }


   $css_directory = get_template_directory().'/css/';
   $all_css_files = array_diff(scandir($css_directory), array('..', '.'));

   //now add the css with wp_enqueue_style()
   foreach($all_css_files as $css_file){
     wp_enqueue_style( $css_file.'-name', get_stylesheet_uri().'/css/'.$css_file );
   }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_all_front_resources');
```

**Disadvantages** in Doing this

- Unwanted resources will be added thus eats server as well browser(many file request and processing all scripts in browser makes little slow)
- You can't give dependency correctly unless you name the js file with dependecy at the end of file name and parse add the dependency in enqueue_scripts and you need to take care of sorting too.

I **Won't recommand** this method. I answered this for the interest of automation. Since you are thinking the dynamic way. Dynamic is good but we needs to be sure that it will work correctly and efficiently.

Comment: thnx WPTC-Troop for your help..I figured out this way that day only so I forgot about this post and it helped me.thnx man much appreciated..And thnx too for your your advice.But in my project whatevere css and js files will be included is required in every pages so I need to include all those assets...

Comment: @PriteshPoddar If you think my answer is correct then you can accept the answer. Thanks for your appreciation